Recast - Inster new line into ast
I have been trying to inster a new line of code into an arrow function using Racast with Espree.
I've been able to create a solution, I felt like I'm doing something incorrect on the parentPath backtracking.
The code below is already in https://astexplorer.net/ format
I've added the code, I'm modifying and my current solution below.


//This is the code Im making the edit to

class SomeCalss extends Yapyap {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.foo = new foo();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    Something.initialize().then((user) => {
        Settings.initialize();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("user not found: ", err);
      })
      .then(() => {
        //Need to add code is arrow function
        //FS.open("abc")
        //FS.open is unique to this calls
        FS.open("xyz")

      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("some more code")
      })
  }
}



export default function transformer(code, { recast, parsers }) {
  const ast = recast.parse(code, { parser: parsers.esprima });
   
        const newcode = ["FS.open('abc')"]
        const astnew = recast.parse(newcode);
  
  recast.visit(ast, {
          visitClassDeclaration(path) {
             if (path.node.id.name === 'SomeCalss') { this.traverse(path) }
             else { return false }
          },
          visitMethodDefinition(path) {
            if (path.node.key.name === 'connectedCallback') { 
               this.traverse(path) 
               
            }
            else { return false }
          },
    
    visitCallExpression(path) {
        if(path.node.callee.type == 'MemberExpression') {
            this.traverse(path)
          if(path.node.callee.object.name == 'FS') {
            const a = path.parentPath.parentPath.parentPath.value.original.body
            const b = path.parentPath.parentPath.value.length
        
            if (typeof(a) == "object") {
               if(a.length == b ){
                    this.traverse(path)
                    console.log(545,path.parentPath.parentPath.value)
                    path.parentPath.parentPath.value.push(astnew.program.body[0])
                }
            }
            //if (typeof(a) != "undefined") return false;
            //if (typeof(b) != "undefined") return false;
           
        
          }else {return false}
        }
        else {return false}
      
    }
  });

  return recast.print(ast).code;
}

